# How do I filter an Angular ng-repeat collection with a function?

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter a list of items in an ng-repeat using `| filter:function`. The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) have an example that filters the list based on what's been entered into an input box. [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kiJyAn?p=preview) is a modification of it where I am attempting to limit the list of friends to just the boys. How do I get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];
  $scope.justBoys = function(item, index, array) {
      console.log(item)
      return item.gender==='boy';
}
});
```

template only access $scope values so you have to put your function in scope

Comment: That answered my question, but I oversimplified it thinking that I could figure out the rest. I didn't. I have updated the Plunker to look a little more like my actual case. I have a list of items and want to group them on the page by a certain field. It's a pretty common thing, so maybe there's a better approach than I'm taking.

Comment: Your plunker not working as expected because you are using "just" instead of "vm.just" in template